# Positioning Divs Within a Wrapper Div - Overflowing

Tags: css, html

I'm currently building a website that contains a structure that I haven't yet built in my experience. It involves a layout that requires multiple sections to be joined together within a wrapper. This is my first time doing this & I'm running into problems. I just want to make sure that I do this correctly. The main issue that I'm running into is a div spilling over & messing up the layout.

**My desired layout:** http://oi40.tinypic.com/2vs403b.jpg

**What I've got so far:** http://tinyurl.com/ognbkx2 You can see the "Lets Connect" portion overflowing & messing up the layout.

How can I fix this? Your help is much appreciated!!!!

**HTML**

```
<div id="about-wrap">
<div class="portrait">
<img src="/andrew/images/andrew.jpg"></img>


<div class="about-me">
ABOUT ME<br>
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-1.jpg"></img>
<p>
Snipped
</p>


<div id="resource-wrap">
<div class="resume"> 
RESUME<br>
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-2.jpg"></img>
PDF | WORD

<div class="connect">
LETS CONNECT<br>
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-3.jpg"></img>
TWITTER | FACEBOOK | LINKEDIN


<div id="exp-thumb-wrap">
I'VE DONE WORK FOR
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-1.jpg"></img>

<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<span class="stretch"></span>


<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<span class="stretch"></span>




</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*About Wrap*/

#about-wrap { 
    position: relative;
    top: 440px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 440px;
    background: #FFFFFF;


}

.about-me {
    height: 160px;
    width: 460px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;


}


/*Resources Wrap*/

#resource-wrap {

    height: 60px;
    width: 460px;
    float: left;



}

.resume {

    height: 60px;
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.connect {

    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;


}

/*Brand Experience Wrap*/


#exp-thumb-wrap {

    height: 160px;
    width: 460px;
    float: left;
}


.exp-thumbs {   
    width: 104px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}


/*Portrait*/


.portait {
    width: 460px;
    height: 408px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: right;

}
```

Comment: Add `float: right` on image and then adjust the `padding`/`margin` of html that is displayed on the left of it

Comment: Also, you don't need to use image for divider, just wrap the text in `span` or `p` and use `border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is infact not overflowing it is because you are including the div inside each other instead of directly putting them unser div `resource-wrap`. See if this is what you are looking for.

#### Html

```
<div id="resource-wrap">
<div class="resume"> 
RESUME<br>
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-2.jpg">
PDF | WORD


</div>
<div class="connect">
LETS CONNECT<br>
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-3.jpg">
TWITTER | FACEBOOK | LINKEDIN



</div>
<div id="exp-thumb-wrap">
I'VE DONE WORK FOR
<img src="/andrew/images/about-divide-1.jpg">

<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<span class="stretch"></span>


<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a class="exp-thumbs" href="#"><img src="/andrew/images/exp-thumb.jpg" alt=""></a>
<span class="stretch"></span>




</div>
</div>
```

#### Css

```
.connect {
height: 60px;
width: 300px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: @Willard You are welcome. You want to learn more on positioning, css etc . this is a good site http://css-tricks.com/

Comment: While this did fix your immediate problem, you should review the other answer as well.  Your page has 3 head sections, a meta tag that isn't in one of the head sections, 2 bodies, 2 doctypes, and incorrectly closed img tags, none of which are valid.

Comment: I'm using php includes to stack pages on top of each other, that I believe is causing the multiple body, header, doctype, etc. tags. What is a better method for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your code is just wrong, open firefox, right click on the page and click "view page source", all the red text is error code, you've got a meta tag outside the head tag. You open head then close it, then close it again, leaving a stray /head tag.

You have a /div tag that isn't closing anything. Its hard to see what tags match with what because they are not indented properly.

You have two doctypes, two heads and two bodies. You should only have one of each per page.

img tags don't end with /img they are just img href="" / (notice the "/")

I suspect once you fix those things your problem might disappear. Its a good place to start, once you've fixed them update the site and see if it's working.

~A

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! I will implement the changes, thank you.

Comment: Not a problem. Post a message here if the issue isn't solved after that and I'll see the notification and check it out again. Be sure to indent everything, its very important for seeing how things will be displayed.